# Implementation of Cassandra sink in Spark streaming using ForeachWriter

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming

Apparently there's no built-in support for a Cassandra sink in Spark streaming. I found this example online which implements a custom Cassandra sink for Spark structured streaming based on ForEachWriter:

https://dzone.com/articles/cassandra-sink-for-spark-structured-streaming

I understand that we need to create a ForeachWriter implementation that takes care of opening a connection to the sink (Cassandra), writing the data and closing the connection. So the `CassandraSinkForeach` and the `CassandraDriver` classes make sense.

However I don't get the need to make SparkSessionBuilder serializable and even the need to initialize the `SparkSession` instance inside the `CassandraDriver` class. Seems like the only reason for doing this is to initialize the `CassandraConnector` from the sparkConf.

According to the `CassandraConnector` docs, a CassandraConnector object can initialized from a CassandraConnectorConfig passed in: http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/2.4.0/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector

Can someone explain if there is a need to initialize SparkSession in the workers? Is this is a general pattern and if so, why the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to Spark 2.4, you can make use of ForEachBatch where you can apply batch writers on top of streaming dataframes.

Comment: Correct, but note that this does not work if you want to use Continuous Processing mode: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreach

Comment: Please update your question, and add information about Continuous Processing Mode :)